# How does Solidity know where to find imports?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I understand how that Solidity can import files stored both externally

```
import "https://github.com/owner/repo/blob/branch/path/to/Contract.sol";
```

and internally

```
import "./Foo.sol";
```

However, when I'm working with hardhat I'm able to get files from the `node_modules` folder easily without working relative to the current directory:

```
import { HardhatUserConfig, task } from "hardhat/config";
```

My question is how does hardhat know to look in the `node_modules` folder for this import? How does solidity know this isn't an external or internal lookup?

Answer (score 0):

Hardhat knows to look in the `node_modules` folder for this import because Hardhat projects are Node.js projects with the hardhat package installed and a `hardhat.config.js` file. To determine whether an import is local or external, Solidity checks to see if the dependency has been installed in your project configuration file. If the dependency has been installed, this is a local import. If not, it gets them via NPM, or a URL (like github, a IPFS gateway, or a Swarm gateway), and this is an external import.